# How can I make this animation with the mouse not running slow on Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, css-animations, transform

I have an animation which is played with the mouse on certain images.
As you can see here, http://dev.ledauphin.popcorn-communication.com/fr/accueil/ , I'm almost there.
But on Firefox, this animation is running really slow...
Anyone has any idea why?
My website: https://dev.ledauphin.popcorn-communication.com/en/home/
My code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.box_effect').hover(function(e) {
      $(document).on("click mousemove", ".box_effect", function(e) {
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        if ($(this).hasClass("right")) {
          console.log($(this));
          var middleX1 = (x - $("#page").width() * 0.69) / 6;
          console.log('right');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("left")) {
          console.log('left');
          var middleX1 = (x - $("#page").width() * 0.31) / 6;
        }
        var middleY1 = (y - $(window).height() * 0.4) / 8;
        var middleX2 = -middleX1 / 2;
        var middleY2 = (-middleY1) / 2;
        var image11 = $(this).find("img");
        image11.css({
          "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + middleX1 + "px," + middleY1 + "px,0px)",
          "-moz-transform": "translate3d(" + middleX1 + "px," + middleY1 + "px,0px)",
          "-ms-transform": "translate3d(" + middleX1 + "px," + middleY1 + "px,0px)",
          "-o-transform": "translate3d(" + middleX1 + "px," + middleY1 + "px,0px)",
          "transform": "translate3d(" + middleX1 + "px," + middleY1 + "px,0px)"
        });
        var image12 = $(this).find(".border");
        image12.css({
          "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + middleX2 + "px," + middleY2 + "px,0px)",
          "-moz-transform": "translate3d(" + middleX2 + "px," + middleY2 + "px,0px)",
          "-ms-transform": "translate3d(" + middleX2 + "px," + middleY2 + "px,0px)",
          "-o-transform": "translate3d(" + middleX2 + "px," + middleY2 + "px,0px)",
          "transform": "translate3d(" + middleX2 + "px," + middleY2 + "px,0px)"
        });
      });
    },
    function() {
      var image11 = $(this).find("img");
      var image12 = $(this).find(".border");
      image11.css({
        "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)",
        "-moz-transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)",
        "-ms-transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)",
        "-o-transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)",
        "transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)"
      });
      image12.css({
        "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)",
        "-moz-transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)",
        "-ms-transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)",
        "-o-transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)",
        "transform": "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px,0px)"
      });
    }
  );

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  width: 75.3%;
  margin: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.row>div {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 6.484vw 3.984vw 4vw;
}

.box_effect {
  padding: 0 3.984vw;
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 4vw;
}

.img_effect {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 2.187vw;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box_effect span.border {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.093vw;
  top: -2.0832vw;
  width: 86.84%;
  height: 97.87%;
  border: 3px solid #91b508;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 380px;
}

.box_effect img {
  max-width: 380px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box_effect .img_effect img,
.box_effect .img_effect span {
  -webkit-transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.92, 0, 0.72)s;
  -moz-transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.92, 0, 0.72)s;
  -ms-transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.92, 0, 0.72)s;
  -o-transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.92, 0, 0.72)s;
  transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.92, 0, 0.72);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="page" class="site">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row one">
        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="right box_effect">
          <div class="img_effect">
            <span class="border" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"></span>
            <img src="https://dev.ledauphin.popcorn-communication.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/choux-fleur.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- #page -->
</body>
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, you probably don't need all of those vendor-specific properties. For instance, `-moz-transform` is only needed if you're supporting Firefox version 15 or below. Considering we're on version 91 of Firefox, it might be time to let that go :). I doubt that will speed things up significantly, but could save some typing. Also, mixing style sheets with inline styles and jQuery (which adds inline styles) is always risky. I suggest using actual CSS animations only (i.e., keyframes and the like).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. But I don't understand how can I use CSS animations only and still get the coordinates of the mouse with JQuery...

Comment: In this website https://pollenlondon.com/, it looks like the value sent has already a transition.